# How do I list products horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have this list that have two products as an example. There could be multiple products but just two right now for this question.

```css
.horizontal {
  display: inline;
  float:left;
}
.product{
    display: block;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
.image{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 180px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left:.45cm;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontalul">
  <li class="horizontal" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="horizontal" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have set the `horizontal` class to display as inline but it doesn't seem to work like I would like it to work. I the items to align horizontally. How can I make them align horizontally?

Comment: just set ```ul``` ```display: flex;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add float:left in your class also use float:right but don't forgot to give next block elements clear:both , try it once

```css
.horizontal {
  display: inline;
  float:left;
  padding:10px 5px;
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-right:5px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="horizontal" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="horizontal" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check my edit. I did this but the results I am getting are not good. List products are squeezing

Comment: I separated both Li s As Individual Check In My Snippet Once

Comment: Here your CSS seems to work but not in my HTML. It doesn't float the products at all :\ can contact me somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="horizontal" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="horizontal" style="display: inline;">
    <div class="product">
      <div class="image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.shingpoint.com.pk/Images/Thumbnails/pc-a1-470-59100-080316082835.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="productname">ASUS VivoMini PC - UN65H-M030M</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        <span>Rs. 37,900</span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Details" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check my edit. I did this but the results I am getting are not good. List products are squeezing

Comment: edit it with all your code and all your styles to see what happen, you may have some wrong or inherited classes that merge styles and dont give the expected result. Check it inspecting your page elements and regarding to styles.

Comment: if you want spacing between one and other product you can add a margin or a padding. But to reach this job it could be better to use bootstrap cols instead an unordered list, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `li {float: left;}` to your style Or if you want to display RTL use `li {float: right;}`

Comment: Check my edit. I did this but the results I am getting are not good. List products are squeezing

Comment: @Ali Rasheed add some paddings that solves squeezing.Like `padding:5px;`